# How to parse .bin file in python according to a specific structure in excel?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, agi-systems-tool-kit

I am trying to visualise some data on STK AGI. First, I need to parse a binary file with a given structure on excel using python and then integrate python with stk to visualise it. Where can I find some documentation that could help?
(the excel file includes hex addr and byte value)

Comment: Ty for the warm welcome. documentation, resources, guidance Id appreciate anything that helps :)

Comment: Sorry, I just found out that asking for any off-site resource is considered off-topic for Stack overflow. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.